# module 'django.db.models' has no attribute 'OnetoOneField'

Tags: django, django-models

I was following a Django tutorial which used models.OnetoOneFiled() in its models.py file. when I tried implementing the same I get his error:

AttributeError: module 'django.db.models' has no attribute 'OnetoOneField'

I have added this line as some of the previous answers suggested but with no luck.

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.db import models

# Create your models here.
class UserProfileInfo(models.Model):

    user = models.OnetoOneField(User,on_delete=models.CASCADE,
        primary_key=True,)
    # additional 

    portfolio_site = models.URLField(blank=True)
    profile_pic = models.ImageField(upload_to='profile_pics',blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.user.username
```

if successful, I should be able to migrate

Comment: It is `OneToOneField` (with uppercase `T`), not `OnetoOneField`.

Comment: Thanks, it worked :)

Answer (score 3):

Its OneToOneField not OnetoOneField